# Count Value occurrences without looping through dictionary

Tags: vba, dictionary, count

In my VBA program I have a dictionary

```
Dim dic As Variant
Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
```

I'm adding a bunch of String items (let's say 100) where some have the value `""`

Example:

```
  Key    |   Value
-------------------
  "A"    |    1
  "B"    |    ""
  "C"    |    3
  "D"    |    4
  "E"    |    ""
 etc.
```

I know there is a way to count the number of key occurrences with `dic.Count("A")` but I would like to count how many Items in my dictionary have the Value `""` (2 in my example) without looping through each item.

I tried the following without success:

```
MsgBox "dic.item()count=" & dic.Item("").Count
MsgBox "dic.item()count=" & dic("").Count
```

How can this be achieved? Is there a way like `dic.Value("").Count` ?

Comment: I don't think it's possible without looping; unless you count the value on the Add: `If myVal = "" Then counter = counter + 1` before the `.Add` on the dictionary object

Comment: @Dave yeah that's my backup plan but if it is possible I prefer it without counter variable.

Comment: Why would you want to avoid looping? It is just a few lines of code and will run quickly even with thousands of entries. VBA isn't like R where you can vectorize your code.

Comment: @JohnColeman You're absolutely right, but if it is possible, I would prefer to have it without loop.

Comment: To avoid loops in that part of the code -- write your own wrapper-class for dictionary objects which contains methods to implement the functionality that you desire.

Comment: @JohnColeman Very clever, thanks for that tip!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<del>This is ugly, but it is not a loop:</del>

As it turns out, this method works very quickly for even super large dictionaries.

```
'Convert the Dictionary to an Array
MyArray = dic.Items
'Convert the Array to a String
MyString = Join(MyArray, ";")
'Blank Items in the Dictionary will result in ";;" appearing in the String
'Split the String on ;;
MyArray = Split(MyString, ";;", -1, vbTextCompare)
'A String with no ";;"'s will result in a 1 element array
'A String with 2 occurances of ;; will give a 3 element array
NumberOfBlankItems = UBound(MyArray)
```

Made some edits to fix a few small logic errors (Split was wrong number of arguments and since it is a zero based array, there's no need to subtract 1)

Also, I test with a 20,000 element dictionary, and there is no appreciable speed difference between looping through the dictionary versus this method. Maybe its not as ugly as I thought...

---

I did one more test using this code:

```
Sub DictionaryTest()
    Dim dic As New Dictionary 'Variant
    Dim r As Long
    Dim key As Variant
    Dim myArray As Variant
    Dim mystring As String
    Dim NumberOfBlankItems As Integer

    Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    For r = 1 To 500000
        dic.Add "Key " & r, CInt(Int((600 * Rnd()) + 1))
    Next

    r = 0

    Debug.Print "Starting count by looping: " & Now()

    For Each key In dic
        If dic.item(key) = 300 Then r = r + 1
    Next

    Debug.Print "Count by looping: " & r

    Debug.Print "Starting count by splitting: " & Now()

    myArray = dic.Items
    mystring = Join(myArray, ";")
    myArray = Split(mystring, "300;", -1, vbTextCompare)
    NumberOfBlankItems = UBound(myArray)
    Debug.Print "Count by splitting: " & NumberOfBlankItems

    Debug.Print "Finish time: " & Now()
End Sub
```

Immediate Window:

```
Starting count by looping: 6/15/2016 3:02:47 PM
Count by looping: 818
Starting count by splitting: 6/15/2016 3:03:16 PM
Count by splitting: 818
Finish time: 6/15/2016 3:03:16 PM
```

As you can see, even with 500,000 entries in the dictionary, the amount of time it takes to split the string (a string with almost 2 billion characters no less!) is still only about 1 second!

Comment: I'm curious to know if its faster than looping through the dictionary! xD

Comment: I did one more test with 500,000 elements in the dictionary. Looping and counting took my HP-asuarus ~29 seconds, but counting by splitting took less than 1 second. It is amazing to me that what I thought would be a kludge to avoid a perfectly logical way to do things turned out to be so much better. As a caveat, care should be taken if the 1st or last elements match the search criteria. Also, a string is limited to ~2 billion characters, so if concatenating all the dictionary elements creates a longer string, you will get an error.

Comment: @Tim Thanks for your dedication to make this answer a perfect one.